# SELECT to only see Offsetting Transactions in table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, partitioning

I have a temp table like this

[image: TblTransactions]

I have been playing with it but I don't know how to get same PortCode,Cusip combo to give me only offsetting transactions (Buy,Sells) not (Purchase,Purchase) combos.

So, I only want to see

> CCC 333333333  Ambition Trust  Purchase,
>
> CCC 333333333  Ambition Trust  Sell

This is the SQL giving me the same Portcode, Cusip combo from a table.

```
SELECT PortfolioName, CUSIP, COUNT(*) AS CNT
INTO #tmpCusip
FROM #tmpTrades 
GROUP BY PortfolioName, MCUSIP
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is there a timestamp or other column in the table that gives order to each subgroup?

Comment: ...is the order in each subgroup important (i.e., Sell then Purchase vs. Purchase then Sell)? Does it start from "zero"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been playing with it but I don't know how to get same PortCode,Cusip combo to give me only offsetting transactions (Buy,Sells) not (Purchase,Purchase) combos.

There is no Buy in your table. You only have Sell and Purchase.

Below is a good starting point for you to get (Purchase,Sell) combo :

```
;with temptrades 
as
(select *, row_number() over (partition  by PortfolioName, [transaction]
order by PortfolioName, [transaction]) as rowNumber
    from tmpTrades
)
select  portcode,cusip, PortfolioName,  [transaction]   
 from temptrades    
where  rowNumber = 1
order by portcode
```

[image]

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b605/1).

Comment: The result set you screenshotted nicely highlights my comment on the question -- the DDD subgroup came out in the opposite order of the OP's screenshot. Is the original data (Sell, Sell, Purchase) or (Sell, Purchase, Sell), etc.? I suppose we don't even know if that's important or not.

Comment: I don't think it is relevant to my question. The partition by should work for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user27642 the comment or the answer ?